# How to read the same column header, but "spelt" differently in new files. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I am writing in python using pandas. The code that I wrote extracts specific column headers from an excel file, which works, but I dont want to have to go into the code everytime to change out the name of the column headers to extract when working on new files with the same data.

Here is my extraction method:

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('filepath')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Tabelle1')

df2 = df[['ZONE_NAME','POLYGONSTRING']]

df2.to_csv('filepath\name', sep=';', index=False, header=True)
```

So When I run this code to another excel file I want it to accept any possible name for "ZONE_NAME" which could be "zonename", "Zone Name" etc...

Comment: Could you show the relevant parts of the code you wrote. You seem to be asking how to not have to reference each individual column each time you load a file, but if you read the file in with ```df = pd.read_excel()``` as you say you did, accessing headers without having to change anything should be as easy as ```columns = list(df.columns.values)```. So definitely include what you've written for a better answer.

Comment: @ralston My apologies, I made edits to the question, does that make a little bit more sense for what im asking?

Sorry im horrible about this site, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is just limited to different ways to write a column like "ZONE_NAME" (e.g., "zone_name", "ZONENAME", "ZONE_name", etc.) then why not just use some type of filter on the column names:

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('filepath')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Tabelle1')

# This will filter out any non-alphabetical characters from each
# column name and lower it (so "ZONE_NAME" "ZONENAME" and "zone_NAME" 
# would become "zonename")
filtered_columns = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', "", c).lower() for c in list(df.columns.values)]
df.columns = filtered_columns

df2 = df[filtered_columns]

df2.to_csv('filepath\name', sep=';', index=False, header=True)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: YES, this is exactly what I have been trying to get at. When I run the above (second) code i get this error though

KeyError: "['locationname' 'locationid' 'zonetype' 'zonename' 'polygonstring'\n 'reservedspaces' 'validfrom' 'validto' 'taxrate' 'remark'] not in index"

Its coming from the "df2 = df[columns]" inline
@ralston

Comment: @Michael I've edited the original answer. Please accept it as an answer and upvote if it helps you.

Comment: im trying but it wont upvote when i click the triangle next to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Pandas read_csv will automatically detect column headers. No need to specify anything ahead of time. Your post is lacking the links to any image, It would be better to post samples of the data in-line though.

Comment: So the excel data there is originally 5 other column headers. "ZONE_NAMES" and "POLYGONSTRINGS" are the ones im slicing out, which works, but when I use this code for other excel files with the same data needed, the column headers may change for the same name if that makes sense; "zonename", "Zone Name" etc... @dartdog

Comment: So, you can access the columns by position instead of label, if that helps? You could just arbitrarily rename the columns to something consistent if that works better. In short it does not seem that it is easy to understand your underlying issue?

Comment: Not familiar with Pandas' read_csv but it doesn't look like it performs string normalization. if it can be used to extract the headers, he could normalize the header string he's looking for and see if that header exists in that extracted list, then perform his extraction method with that string. Also not a python developer, sticking my head where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Agree but the initial draft of the question was not clear, it is improving 

Comment: My apologies, So yes accessing the label postion would work, but then theres a issue if the label changes position in a new excel file when applying the code. Basically need a way of ignoring label position and how it is appearing. accessing how the label appears was my only way to ignore the positioning. @dartdog